# efficient algorithm to find nearest point in a graph that does not have a known equation

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I'm asking this questions out of curiostity, since my quick and dirty implementation seems to be good enough.  However I'm curious what a better implementation would be.

I have a graph of real world data.  There are no duplicate X values and the X value increments at a consistant rate across the graph, but Y data is based off of real world output.  I want to find the nearest point on the graph from an arbitrary given point P programmatically.  I'm trying to find an efficient (ie fast) algorithm for doing this.  I don't need the the exact closest point, I can settle for a point that is 'nearly' the closest point.

The obvious lazy solution is to increment through every single point in the graph, calculate the distance, and then find the minimum of the distance.  This however could theoretically be slow for large graphs; too slow for what I want.

Since I only need an approximate closest point I imagine the ideal fastest equation would involve generating a best fit line and using that line to calculate where the point should be in real time; but that sounds like a potential mathematical headache I'm not about to take on.

My solution is a hack which works only because I assume my point P isn't arbitrary, namely I assume that P will usually be close to my graph line and when that happens I can cross out the distant X values from consideration.  I calculating how close the point on the line that shares the X coordinate with P is and use the distance between that point and P to calculate the largest/smallest X value that could possible be closer points.

I can't help but feel there should be a faster algorithm then my solution (which is only useful because I assume 99% of the time my point P will be a point close to the line already).  I tried googling for better algorithms but found so many algorithms that didn't quite fit that it was hard to find what I was looking for amongst all the clutter of inappropriate algorithms.  So, does anyone here have a suggested algorithm that would be more efficient?  Keep in mind I don't need a full algorithm since what I have works for my needs, I'm just curious what the proper solution would have been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a data structure, some common data structures for spacial searching (including nearest neighbour) are...

- quad-tree (and octree etc).
- kd-tree
- bsp tree (only practical for a static set of points).
- r-tree

The r-tree comes in a number of variants. It's very closely related to the B+ tree, but with (depending on the variant) different orderings on the items (points) in the leaf nodes.

The Hilbert R tree uses a strict ordering of points based on the Hilbert curve. The Hilbert curve (or rather a generalization of it) is very good at ordering multi-dimensional data so that nearby points in space are usually nearby in the linear ordering.

In principle, the Hilbert ordering could be applied by sorting a simple array of points. The natural clustering in this would mean that a search would usually only need to search a few fairly-short spans in the array - with the complication being that you need to work out which spans they are.

I used to have a link for a good paper on doing the Hilbert curve ordering calculations, but I've lost it. An ordering based on Gray codes would be simpler, but not quite as efficient at clustering. In fact, there's a deep connection between Gray codes and Hilbert curves - that paper I've lost uses Gray code related functions quite a bit.

**EDIT** - I found that link - http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.133.7490

Answer (score 4):

If you store the [x,y] points in a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) you'll be able to find the closest one quickly (something like O(log n)). I think that's the best you can do without making assumptions about where the point is going to be. Rather than repeat the algorithm here have a look at this [link](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/Workshops/MiningTutorial/pindyk-slides.ppt).

Your solution is pretty good, by examining how the points vary in y couldn't you calculate a bound for the number of points along the x axis you need to examine instead of using an arbitrary one.

Comment: I'm sadly stuck with an array of points, but for the generic problem I posed a better data structure would probably be the best solution.  However, could you elaborate on how you would be using the quadtree?

Comment: Quadtrees are one of a number of data structures that work by recursively partitioning space. It's easy to search for *a* nearby (same atomic region) point, slightly more awkward to search for the nearest - needs depth-first/breadth-first/priority-ordered searching.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your point `P=(x,y)` and your real-world data is a function `y=f(x)`

Step 1: Calculate `r=|f(x)-y|`.

Step 2: Find points in the interval `I=(x-r,x+r)`

Step 3: Find the closest point in `I` to `P`.

Comment: the problem is calculating the f(x).  how would I go about doing that without adding massive complexity to my code?

Comment: Sorry, `f(x)` is your "real-world data". It's the y-value of your data at x.

Comment: okay sorry, misread your answer.  That is close to what I did, except that I used the square of distance as my for r instead of f(X) -y. Maybe I'm just not thinking clearly, but it seems like this won't work without a square or square-root somewhere due to distance being based off of the square of X and Y.  (my brain isn't functioning fully right now so I can't be sure I'm just not being stupid heh)

Comment: Actually I just realized that this results in an exact answer, not an approximation. Draw a picture. Draw a curve for your function and a point `P`. Now draw a circle around `P` with radius `r` (as defined in my answer). There's no way for a point outside of `I` to be contained within that circle.